# Apple App Store

Tags: app-store, registration, google-play

I have a non-technical question, but it is of high importance to those who want to start independent app development.

Google's Play store limits its Merchant developers (the ones who can charge apps) to certain countries. What about Apple's App store? I tried to search for such conditions but couldn't find

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides long list of countries to sell your apps over 150 countries, however you cannot sell apps in few embargoed countries by us, cuba, Iran, north korea, syria, sudan. you can gain access to more information at

https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/
http://www.umresearch.umd.edu/ORAA/export_control_guidance/docs/Embargoed%20Countries.pdf

Hope this helps.